# Is it normal for the Target Audience to be displayed as a GUID in email alerts?

Tags: audience-targeting, email

On MOSS 2007 SP2, I have an announcement list that had audience targetting enabled.  Users have email alerts set on that list for when new items change.  The email displays the tartget audience as a guid - is that normal?

I tried to google for the information, but the [closest I could find](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointecm/thread/252cfba9-f3e0-4dc3-81d8-2c9a391e3037) talks about the problem showing up in the version history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Global audiences are stored as GUIDs within the audience targeting field, and the default email alert template doesn't do any extra formatting to make it more user-friendly.